# Extend TypoLink Function to append GET parameters depending on pId

Tags: typo3, extbase, typolink

Hoe can I extend the TypoLink generation Function that every time a TypoLink is being generated it checks for a certain targetpId and then append the id of the current page as a GEt argument. For example:

```
When a Link on the page with ID 5 targets the page with the ID 19 then add ?ref=5 to the link
```

I currently don't know where to start, which Class/Method can I try to Override to include this kind of behaviour.

Comment: Maybe it is easier to solve with a RedirectRule in .htaccess?

Comment: How should that work? I would like to place a link on any page which leads to a page with a certain id. And these links should get a get parameter from the page where the link is placed. I don't think that its possible via .htaccess

Comment: I see. Can you explain, why do you want to do it? It seems like you want do to something on id=19 with the referer URL/id? Other idea is to do it in typoscript.

Comment: The main reason for this is that we have various links on a website wich say "log in and you see a nice image of a cat" Then it links to the login page and after the login is done we want to redirect the user to the page where he come from.
A Classic redirect after login, the problem is that we cant work with the referrer data because when you are on a other page on the website and just go to the login page by yourself, you end up on the page where you come from. Which is not intended.

Answer (score 1):

[Extending Classes (XCLASSes)](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Xclasses/Index.html)

I dont know about TYPO3 9.5 but we did it in 8.7.
Here is a snippet about the extended classes we used:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['Objects'][TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Page\PageRepository::class] = array(
    'className' => Vendor\Extension\Page\PageRepository::class
);

$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['Objects'][TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\ContentObject\ContentObjectRenderer::class] = array(
    'className' => Vendor\Extension\ContentObject\ContentObjectRenderer::class
);

$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['Objects'][TYPO3\CMS\Core\DataHandling\DataHandler::class] = array(
    'className' => Vendor\Extension\DataHandling\DataHandler::class
);

$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['Objects'][TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Typolink\PageLinkBuilder::class] = array(
    'className' => Vendor\Extension\Typolink\PageLinkBuilder::class
);
```

Its not exactly what you are searching for but a good way to start.

Comment: Thank you, thats indeed a great kickstart.